# Replace Document with new HTML (including scripts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now I get the HTML of a page using AJAX, and I modify the DOM using jQuery, I can do that part perfectly.

I load the new HTML using this code:

```
document.body.parentElement.innerHTML = newDoc.body.parentElement.innerHTML;
```

It loads perfectly new HTML, the problem is that it doesn't load all the scripts, so I found a solution:

https://ghinda.net/article/script-tags/

The problem with this is the inline  that has document.write because it overwrites the whole page.

For example:

```
<script>document.write("Hello");</script>
```

On the original script it writes where is placed without overwriting whole document.

I don't want to load the new document using document.write as some browser don't respect the load of scripts, I found this method better.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, override the document.write function.

To this one:

```
document.write = function() {
var e = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, "");
if (document.currentScript) document.currentScript.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", e);
else {
    var t = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    t[t.length - 1].insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", e)
 }
};
```

I hope someone find this useful